# XACML for dynamic authorization using time and date

Tags: xacml, xacml2, alfa, abac

Please, I would like to know how to write XACML policy for dynamic control. I want to control user permission to access attribute with time or date.

Comment: WHy XACML 2.0? What engine are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be more specific in your question if you want us to help with the XACML policy.

Generally you can use the ALFA plugin for Eclipse to write an ALFA policy that will get automatically converted on the fly into a XACML 3.0 policy.

In your question, you say:

> I want to control user permission to access attribute with time or date.

Your XACML policy could look like

```
policy example{
    target clause currentDate>"2014-06-01":date and currentTime>"07:00:00":time
    apply firstApplicable
    rule allowAccessManagers{
        target clause role=="manager"
        permit
    }

}
```

You can download the ALFA plugin [here](http://www.axiomatics.com/alfa-plugin-for-eclipse.html).